# how to write RDF in original format

Tags: rdf4j

RDF4J Newbie question -

When I load this RDF from file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

<foaf:Person>
 <foaf:name>My Name</foaf:name>
</foaf:Person>

</rdf:RDF>
```

using this code

```
String fileName = "foaf.rdf";
try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Model model = Rio.parse(is, "", RDFFormat.RDFXML);
    System.out.println();
    Rio.write(model, System.out, RDFFormat.RDFXML);
    System.out.println();
    is.close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1basf0r6vx1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
    <foaf:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">My Name</foaf:name>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

How would I go about getting RDF printed out in the original format?

Comment: What is your use case? Why would you need to get the exact same format back?

Comment: A WYSIWYG ontology editor. If user uploads a document in a valid certain format, they want to see it back in the same format.

Comment: Will be a bit hard. You provided here a foaf:person but without any real identifier like a URI. RDF4J creates a BNode to handle your data and thats why you get this slightly changed file. And if it is a WYSIWIG Ontology editor like Protegé I don't see why your user need to see the file.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if I'm missing anything, looks like I'm  not:) Unfortunately, this has to be completely browser based, so Protege isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

RDF4J has also a pretty print function. Maybe this can help you with your output.

You just have to create a writer and then set pretty print to true.

```
Rio.createWriter(format, outputStream).set(BasicWriterSettings.PRETTY_PRINT, true)
```